# Yubikey stops TouchID from working

Tags: login, touch-id, smart-card

I use a Yubikey Nano (USB-C) and it allows me to 2FA very conveniently.

When I plugged it in, my macOS gave me the option to pair it with my login account and use it as a way of logging in as well. I was happy to do that as it shortened the password at times when I needed to use it.

However, the side effect has been that my TouchID is no longer active, as I never get the opportunity to enter my macOS login password. And that is required for TouchID to do its thing.

I can trigger the password prompt by forcing scenarios that required TouchID to work (for example, triggering biometric auth in software like Bitwarden.)

I can also do the same by temporarily unplugging the Yubikey every time I reboot.

Is there a cleaner way of prompting TouchID to arm itself by asking me my macOS login password? A shell command maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to settings -> TouchID and Password -> add a new fingerprint.
The system will ask you to enter your password, and you can use Touch ID.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial to do in Terminal.app. Just run a basic command with sudo.

eg `sudo echo "some text"`

The system will prompt you for your password and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the security configuration might prompt macOS to ask for your password and re-enable Touch ID. This can be done with the following command: `sudo rm /var/db/auth.db`